# How to set up SQLITE for laravel webserver?

Tags: sqlite, laravel

I want to use SQLITE for my laravel5 project on my webserver. I migrated my local laravel 5 project onto my AWS ec2 lamp Ubuntu server. http://realtoraxe.com/realtoraxe/public/ but it shows

```
InvalidArgumentException in SQLiteConnector.php line 34: Database does not exist.
```

I changed the database.php set for sqlite

```
 <?php
 return array(
    'default' => 'sqlite',
    'connections' => array(
    'sqlite' => array(
    'driver'   => 'sqlite',
    'database' =>    'http://realtoraxe.com/realtoraxe/storage/database.sqlite',
    'prefix'   => '',
     ),
   ),
  );
 ?>
```

and I changed the .env to

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=mystring
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

when I do
    php artisan migrate
it says there is no database

I think what I wrote as the path for the database in the database.php is wrong and do I may need to somehow write where my ip adress is in the .env file? I have been googling all night and can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: There are default sqlite config options in `database.php`.  Because it already expects the file to be in your storage folder and named `database.sqlite`, the only thing you have to do is add `DB_CONNECTION=sqlite` to your .env file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You dont need to edit the .php files at all. You can all do it in the .env file, since the files in the config directory are written to first use the values from the .env file, and if they are not defined, fall back on what is defined there.

`env('DB_CONNECTION','mysql')` would yield the value from the .env file, and only if it is not defined fall back to mysql.

So in your .env file just put the following:

`DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=database/database.sqlite`

and create a file called `database.sqlite` in your `database` directory (thats where its supposed to be by convention.). That's it.

Answer (score 5):

For default laravel 5.2+ installation:

create an sqlite database file

```
$ cd storage
$ touch database.sqlite
$ cd ..
```

make it writeable

```
$ chmod -R 777 storage
```

at ".env" file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=storage/database.sqlite
```

and remove or comment all other DB_* records

If you prefer to use relative path, instead of absolute to database file
at "config/database.php"

instead of:

```
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
```

write:

```
'database' => __DIR__ . '/../' . env( 'DB_DATABASE' ),
```

now, laravel app will be able to find sqlite file, and php artisan will work too

Comment: Any reason to store it in the storage directory instead of the database directory?

Comment: FYI: Actually that changed in Laravel 9. It is now saved in `database`. @kjones

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using HTTP link? I guess it should link to a `.sqlite` DB file:

```
'database' => __DIR__.'/../database/production.sqlite',
```

http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/118/setting-up-the-sqlite-database-driver

Comment: yeah. thats an http link. Do i need to add anything else to my .env file?

Comment: @user432495, so did you understand that you can't use HTTP link? You should give a link to the concrete file.

Comment: yeah. The file is in the /database/database.sqlite. I wrote the line as  'database' => __DIR__.'/../database/database.sqlite', (It still doesn't see it)